# Remove next line after specific character

Tags: text-processing

I would like to remove the word that comes after a specific character in a text file.
For instance:

```
.
I
am
Anders
<<
Thank
you
```

to be

```
.
am
Anders
<<
you
```

or

```
am
Anders
you
```

How is that possible? I can remove the dots by saying:

```
sed 's/\.*//' *.txt
```

Kind regards
Anders

Comment: Does your file have just one word per line?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN {next_out = 1} {out = next_out; next_out = 1} /^[.]/ {next_out = 0} out' < some_text_file` (And then it’s a matter of adding all relevant characters into the regexp or otherwise adjusting it to match everything you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
$ cat file
.
I
am
Anders
<<
Thank
you
```

then

```
$ sed '/[.<]/{n;d;}' file
.
am
Anders
<<
you
```

and

```
$ sed '/[.<]/{N;d;}' file
am
Anders
you
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works :-)